# Spring Data JPA QueryLimit

Tags: spring, jpa, limit

@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM user Order By e.id DESC LIMIT 0, :n ")
    List findTopN(@Param("n") long n);

Comment: Don't post changes to your code as comments, edit your question instead. If you want to limit the results add an argument of type `Pageable` to your method signature and remove the `LIMIT` clause from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM event_tracker.user  Order By user.id DESC LIMIT 0, :n",nativeQuery = true)
    List findTopN(@Param("n") long n);